# How to play .3gp audio file in console?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, 3gp

I have to play a 3gp audio file present in my PC via a Java console program.  I am **not using applet... or Swing *only console***.

How to play .3gp audio file in console?

Comment: The first hurdle you need to overcome is that Java does not support `.3gp` by default, so you will need to find a Service Provider Interface (a reader for the format) that does.

Comment: You may want to check out http://fmj-sf.net/ - a Java library around FFmpeg

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281353/use-java-ffmpeg-wrapper-or-simply-use-java-runtime-to-execute-ffmpeg

Comment: Add @Joe to comments so Joe gets notified.  ;)