# convert jpgs and mp3 to flv using java

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, flv

Now I am trying to convert a few jpg files and a mp3 to flv file.

The ffmpeg command can do this.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i music.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -tune stillimage -c:a copy output.mkv
```

but I must use this function in my java project ):

Are there any java opensource projects?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would be relevant to you, but I think it would be helpful:

[use java-ffmpeg wrapper, or simply use java runtime to execute ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281353/) and more precisely the answer with the highest score:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281454/1091386 which is, of course, 4 years old. Following the second link to the forum thread http://red5.5842.n7.nabble.com/java-call-ffmpeg-td25005.html seems to suggest something like

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("ffmpeg");
```

might work for your case. Of course, you will want to pass in options separately...