# Library that can extract and play video file

Tags: java, video, mp4, extractor

I will build a simple program that

1. Can play video file (.mp4) in my program.
2. Can extract the video, so that I can get the title, length, subtitle, and the audio, etc.

What is the library in Java that I should use?

I have googled, but I still can not find the best library. By the way, I have tried to download xuggler, but I can not find any file.exe that can install this library.
Please be kind because I never make a code regarding video player and video extractor.

Comment: Following link should help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281353/use-java-ffmpeg-wrapper-or-simply-use-java-runtime-to-execute-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successed to use xuggler in java. Xuggler website is suck because they don't keep good installer in their website. Every beginner who use xuggler must be have some trouble like me.

For every one who want to use Xuggler, you can follow this website
http://www.benfarahmand.com/2012/11/tutorial-using-xuggler-in-processing.html

the link to download file.exe xuggler is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh7zcyilibzfoyb/xuggle-xuggler.5.1.0-win64-setup.exe

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For playing audio and video in your java program use `Java Media Framework`. It contains jar files that will provide you classes to play and handle audio and video files.

Use [this](http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/tutorial/jmf_tutorial.pdf) tutorial for understanding of JMF.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually, I have downloaded JMF and try to run it. I run windows 64 bit. I read some issue on internet that said, JMF just support for 32 bit windows. Is it true?

Comment: Actually I have not tried it with 64 bit. I just tried with 32bit windows only. But by google I found some source that say, It is possible to run JMS on 64 bit also. please try [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2134405).