# humble-video (Xuggle) problem with codecs and mp4 files

Tags: java, xuggler, xuggle

I'm trying to use this new library (humble-video) based on Xuggle:

https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video

but I have some problems: mp4 files are not working:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

On the other hand the following are pleyed without problems:

http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp
http://www.engr.colostate.edu/me/facil/dynamics/files/drop.avi

using the class: DecodeAndPlayVideo provided within the project:

```
import io.humble.video.Decoder;
import io.humble.video.Demuxer;
import io.humble.video.DemuxerStream;
import io.humble.video.Global;
import io.humble.video.Media;
import io.humble.video.MediaDescriptor;
import io.humble.video.MediaPacket;
import io.humble.video.MediaPicture;
import io.humble.video.Rational;
import io.humble.video.awt.ImageFrame;
import io.humble.video.awt.MediaPictureConverter;
import io.humble.video.awt.MediaPictureConverterFactory;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

/**
 * Opens a media file, finds the first video stream, and then plays it.
 * This is meant as a demonstration program to teach the use of the Humble API.
 * <p>
 * Concepts introduced:
 * </p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>MediaPicture: {@link MediaPicture} objects represent uncompressed video in Humble.</li>
 * <li>Timestamps: All {@link Media} objects in Humble have a timestamp, and this demonstration introduces the concept of having to worry about <i>when</i> to display information.</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * <p> 
 * To run from maven, do:
 * </p>
 * <pre>
 * mvn install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="io.humble.video.demos.DecodeAndPlayVideo" -Dexec.args="filename.mp4"
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author aclarke
 *
 */
public class DecodeAndPlayVideo {

  /**
   * Opens a file, and plays the video from it on a screen at the right rate.
   * @param filename The file or URL to play.
   */
  private static void playVideo(String filename) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    /*
     * Start by creating a container object, in this case a demuxer since
     * we are reading, to get video data from.
     */
    Demuxer demuxer = Demuxer.make();

    /*
     * Open the demuxer with the filename passed on.
     */
    demuxer.open(filename, null, false, true, null, null);

    /*
     * Query how many streams the call to open found
     */
    int numStreams = demuxer.getNumStreams();

    /*
     * Iterate through the streams to find the first video stream
     */
    int videoStreamId = -1;
    long streamStartTime = Global.NO_PTS;
    Decoder videoDecoder = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      final DemuxerStream stream = demuxer.getStream(i);
      streamStartTime = stream.getStartTime();
      final Decoder decoder = stream.getDecoder();
      if (decoder != null && decoder.getCodecType() == MediaDescriptor.Type.MEDIA_VIDEO) {
        videoStreamId = i;
        videoDecoder = decoder;
        // stop at the first one.
        break;
      }
    }
    if (videoStreamId == -1)
      throw new RuntimeException("could not find video stream in container: "+filename);

    /*
     * Now we have found the audio stream in this file.  Let's open up our decoder so it can
     * do work.
     */
    videoDecoder.open(null, null);

    final MediaPicture picture = MediaPicture.make(
        videoDecoder.getWidth(),
        videoDecoder.getHeight(),
        videoDecoder.getPixelFormat());

    /** A converter object we'll use to convert the picture in the video to a BGR_24 format that Java Swing
     * can work with. You can still access the data directly in the MediaPicture if you prefer, but this
     * abstracts away from this demo most of that byte-conversion work. Go read the source code for the
     * converters if you're a glutton for punishment.
     */
    final MediaPictureConverter converter = 
        MediaPictureConverterFactory.createConverter(
            MediaPictureConverterFactory.HUMBLE_BGR_24,
            picture);
    BufferedImage image = null;

    /**
     * This is the Window we will display in. See the code for this if you're curious, but to keep this demo clean
     * we're 'simplifying' Java AWT UI updating code. This method just creates a single window on the UI thread, and blocks
     * until it is displayed.
     */
    final ImageFrame window = ImageFrame.make();
    if (window == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Attempting this demo on a headless machine, and that will not work. Sad day for you.");
    }

    /**
     * Media playback, like comedy, is all about timing. Here we're going to introduce <b>very very basic</b>
     * timing. This code is deliberately kept simple (i.e. doesn't worry about A/V drift, garbage collection pause time, etc.)
     * because that will quickly make things more complicated. 
     * 
     * But the basic idea is there are two clocks:
     * <ul>
     * <li>Player Clock: The time that the player sees (relative to the system clock).</li>
     * <li>Stream Clock: Each stream has its own clock, and the ticks are measured in units of time-bases</li>
     * </ul>
     * 
     * And we need to convert between the two units of time. Each MediaPicture and MediaAudio object have associated
     * time stamps, and much of the complexity in video players goes into making sure the right picture (or sound) is
     * seen (or heard) at the right time. This is actually very tricky and many folks get it wrong -- watch enough
     * Netflix and you'll see what I mean -- audio and video slightly out of sync. But for this demo, we're erring for
     * 'simplicity' of code, not correctness. It is beyond the scope of this demo to make a full fledged video player.
     */

    // Calculate the time BEFORE we start playing.
    long systemStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    // Set units for the system time, which because we used System.nanoTime will be in nanoseconds.
    final Rational systemTimeBase = Rational.make(1, 1000000000);
    // All the MediaPicture objects decoded from the videoDecoder will share this timebase.
    final Rational streamTimebase = videoDecoder.getTimeBase();

    /**
     * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet. This
     * is a decoding loop, and as you work with Humble you'll write a lot
     * of these.
     * 
     * Notice how in this loop we reuse all of our objects to avoid
     * reallocating them. Each call to Humble resets objects to avoid
     * unnecessary reallocation.
     */
    final MediaPacket packet = MediaPacket.make();
    while(demuxer.read(packet) >= 0) {
      /**
       * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our video stream
       */
      if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId)
      {
        /**
         * A packet can actually contain multiple sets of samples (or frames of samples
         * in decoding speak).  So, we may need to call decode  multiple
         * times at different offsets in the packet's data.  We capture that here.
         */
        int offset = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do {
          bytesRead += videoDecoder.decode(picture, packet, offset);
          if (picture.isComplete()) {
            image = displayVideoAtCorrectTime(streamStartTime, picture,
                converter, image, window, systemStartTime, systemTimeBase,
                streamTimebase);
          }
          offset += bytesRead;
        } while (offset < packet.getSize());
      }
    }

    // Some video decoders (especially advanced ones) will cache
    // video data before they begin decoding, so when you are done you need
    // to flush them. The convention to flush Encoders or Decoders in Humble Video
    // is to keep passing in null until incomplete samples or packets are returned.
    do {
      videoDecoder.decode(picture, null, 0);
      if (picture.isComplete()) {
        image = displayVideoAtCorrectTime(streamStartTime, picture, converter,
            image, window, systemStartTime, systemTimeBase, streamTimebase);
      }
    } while (picture.isComplete());

    // It is good practice to close demuxers when you're done to free
    // up file handles. Humble will EVENTUALLY detect if nothing else
    // references this demuxer and close it then, but get in the habit
    // of cleaning up after yourself, and your future girlfriend/boyfriend
    // will appreciate it.
    demuxer.close();

    // similar with the demuxer, for the windowing system, clean up after yourself.
    window.dispose();
  }

  /**
   * Takes the video picture and displays it at the right time.
   */
  private static BufferedImage displayVideoAtCorrectTime(long streamStartTime,
      final MediaPicture picture, final MediaPictureConverter converter,
      BufferedImage image, final ImageFrame window, long systemStartTime,
      final Rational systemTimeBase, final Rational streamTimebase)
      throws InterruptedException {
    long streamTimestamp = picture.getTimeStamp();
    // convert streamTimestamp into system units (i.e. nano-seconds)
    streamTimestamp = systemTimeBase.rescale(streamTimestamp-streamStartTime, streamTimebase);
    // get the current clock time, with our most accurate clock
    long systemTimestamp = System.nanoTime();
    // loop in a sleeping loop until we're within 1 ms of the time for that video frame.
    // a real video player needs to be much more sophisticated than this.
    while (streamTimestamp > (systemTimestamp - systemStartTime + 1000000)) {
      Thread.sleep(1);
      systemTimestamp = System.nanoTime();
    }
    // finally, convert the image from Humble format into Java images.
    image = converter.toImage(image, picture);
    // And ask the UI thread to repaint with the new image.
    window.setImage(image);
    return image;
  }

  /**
   * Takes a media container (file) as the first argument, opens it,
   * opens up a window and plays back the video.
   *  
   * @param args Must contain one string which represents a filename
   * @throws IOException 
   * @throws InterruptedException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
  {



    if (args==null || args.length==0 ) {
        args = new String[] {"http://62.210.141.18:1935/directo/lancelot.television/live.m3u8"};
    }
    final Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("h", "help", false, "displays help");
    options.addOption("v", "version", false, "version of this library");

    final CommandLineParser parser = new org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser();
    try {
      final CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
      if (cmd.hasOption("version")) {
        // let's find what version of the library we're running
        final String version = io.humble.video_native.Version.getVersionInfo();
        System.out.println("Humble Version: " + version);
      } else if (cmd.hasOption("help") || args.length == 0) {
        final HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        formatter.printHelp(DecodeAndPlayVideo.class.getCanonicalName() + " <filename>", options);
      } else {
        final String[] parsedArgs = cmd.getArgs();
        for(String arg: parsedArgs)
          playVideo(arg);
      }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      System.err.println("Exception parsing command line: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  }


}
```

Is there any reason? did I miss something?

I have also tried with a live stream:
http://62.210.141.18:1935/directo/lancelot.television/live.m3u8

And I get:

```
ERROR io.humble.video.DemuxerStream - HumbleRuntimeError("could not find decoding codec"): could not find decoding codec (DemuxerStream.cpp:71)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find decoding codec
    at io.humble.video.VideoJNI.DemuxerStream_getDecoder(Native Method)
    at io.humble.video.DemuxerStream.getDecoder(DemuxerStream.java:140)
    at com.example.test.DecodeAndPlayVideo.playVideo(DecodeAndPlayVideo.java:81)
    at com.example.test.DecodeAndPlayVideo.main(DecodeAndPlayVideo.java:266)
```

How can I add codecs?

Comment: may the author answer soon - I question your attempt/choice to use something that relies on something etc but if it's for your experimentation fine - as you can see right off while the author says "100s of codecs" you failed already at the most basic one - I think ffmpeg will be an easier thing if you want to process videos in your program

Comment: Thank you , can you please help me to find a good starting point to use ffmpeg in java to play video and maybe also explaying how to manage the different codecs?

Comment: To play it would be the easiest - to process it would require more - you just have to invoke ffplay from the runtime - you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281353/use-java-ffmpeg-wrapper-or-simply-use-java-runtime-to-execute-ffmpeg for some attempts and further read - you will need some programming skill though (e.g. Runtime etc) - the codecs are handled by ffmpeg you dont have to worry - they continually cover more and more

Comment: I need to put the video in a Jframe o a Canvas, is that possible?

Comment: it is possible but more involved - in that case better stick with this or see other people's wrappers

Comment: Just use JavaCV or OpenCV+Java, you will be fine. You can start here:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv